# LazyLoad validation errors

Tags: html, wordpress, lazy-loading

I developed an online store on Wordpress + Woocommerce.

https://www.haifa-flower.co.il/

To optimize the download speed, I used the WP Rocket plugin. After activating LazyLoad, a large number of errors appeared in the validator.

LazyLoad makes my page load faster. Wouldn't want to turn it off. How can I remove these errors?

The plugin support service told me that the errors are not critical. This is true?

[validation errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dUsU.png)

Comment: I can't see any errors appearing on your shop. Did you disable the Rocket plugin?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of causes / solutions for this situation.

Just mentioning a couple of options:

- WP Rocket (or some other plugin) has enabled rendering responsive
  images, which require 'srcset=""'
- Plugin loading order is incorrect,    which could be caused by WP
  Rocket

Debug:

- Try disabling functions in WP Rocket to find out the cause
- Add / overrule HTML with 'srcset' added to see if your problem is
  solved

If you have control over your webserver, you could (in case you use NGINX / Apache) install mod_pagespeed, which takes a lot of work out of your hands and can do really cool stuff which makes your shop load much faster! (Just a hint)

Hope this helped you a bit solving the problem! Good luck